# Message numbers with Javamail API

Tags: email, imap, jakarta-mail

I'm wondering how message numbers in the JavaMail API work.
Are they always sorted by time?

What I'm trying to do is avoid refetching headers on a gmail folder.
Let's say I have a folder with 20,000 messages, that I process today.
Tomorrow, there's a 100 new messages, and I would prefer not to fetch all
20,000 headers again. Can I just ask for msg nums. 20,001 - 20,100?
I assume this would work in the normal case where later messages are added
to folders. But how about the case that a user manually inserts something
from an earlier time period into the folder using a client like Thunderbird?

[s]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the server that controls how message numbers work.  In essentially all cases, message numbers correspond to the order in which message are added to the mailbox.

In your Inbox, for example, this is the order in which messages are **received**.  Your email client might display the messages in the order in which they were sent, which can be quite different.

Messages might be removed from the list, but messages are never inserted before an existing message.  If you're looking for new message, you have to handle the case where an existing message was deleted, changing the message numbers.

See the JavaMail UIDFolder interface, and the IMAP spec on which it was based.  If you keep track of the last UID you've seen, you'll only need to look at messages with UIDs larger than that.  There's lots more details, but that's a start.  Read the docs and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. That works. Also, I found that the folder's message numbers also increment (i.e., even if a message with an earlier timestamp gets added to a Gmail folder, it appears later in folder.getMessages()). But I'll rely on the UIDs instead.

Comment: If you have 10 messages and add another it will be #11.  If you then delete the first 5 messages and add 5 new messages, message #11 is a different message entirely.  That's why you need to use UIDs.